# How do I create a conditional sum to add numbers when one string matches another?

Tags: excel

I have an Excel 2010 spreadsheet, which has a column of strings (A) and a column of numbers (B).  I have a third column elsewhere on the sheet (column S), which I have used as a source to build a drop-down list to populate column A.

I want now to create a fourth column beside S, which will hold numerical values (column T).  I want the values in this column to be the sum of all the numerical values in B if and only if the string in column A beside B matches the string in S beside T.  This is difficult to describe.  I will try to show it by example.

Column A: "apple", "banana", "apple", "orange", "apple", "banana"

Column B: 2, 4, 9, 1, 8, 2

Column S: "apple", "banana", "orange"

Column T: 19, 6, 1

Now in cell T1 (i.e. the numerical value beside the source string "apple"), I want this to be the sum of B1 + B3 + B5 = 19 (i.e. the numerical values from B where the string immediately to the left in column A is equal to "apple").

I hope that is understandable.  I have tried several variations of the conditional sum functions and the EXACT function, but I don't seem to be able to get anything to work.

I could easily work out how to do this procedurally, but I've never used VBA in Excel, so I figure it would take me a while to work out the syntax for the code I need.

Comment: Patrick, I see that you have never accepted answers to any of your questions (including from the past).  Any reason, why?

Comment: I too came here from where you came @Bala. And I came, I downvoted Patrick, and I commented!

Comment: Lame but true: I honestly didn't know you could click the actual check-mark.  I thought that was just an icon for the up/down-vote function above it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
column A: "a","b","a","o","a","b"
column B: 2,4,9,1,8,2
column D: "a","b","o"
column E(1): =SUMIF(A1:A6,D1,B1:B6) #=> Gives you 19
column E(2): =SUMIF(A1:A6,D2,B1:B6) #=> Gives you 6
```

Comment: This worked a treat. I can't believe it turned out to be so simple.  Thank you. - Patrick

Answer (score 1):

formulat in T1 =

```
=SUMIF(A:A, S1, B:B)
```

copy the formula and paste into entire column T

Comment: Sorry - didn't try this, 'cos I'm probably being thick, but I don't understand it.  Thanks for the reply though.